# App crashes after few seconds

Tags: android

I am working on an app which dosen't show me any errors and runs just fine, but after a second just crashes, I tried everything but could not find the error (being new) can someone please tell me where am I doing wrong as

logcat

```
 11-08 12:57:16.011    5886-5886/com.koshur.socialnetwork E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.koshur.socialnetwork, PID: 5886
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.koshur.socialnetwork.adapters.HomeListAdapter.setPosts(java.util.List)' on a null object reference
            at com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview.updateView(ProfilePreview.java:334)
            at com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview.access$300(ProfilePreview.java:42)
            at com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview$5.success(ProfilePreview.java:308)
            at com.koshur.socialnetwork.activities.ProfilePreview$5.success(ProfilePreview.java:300)
            at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5293)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

java class

```
public class ProfilePreview extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {
public TextView userProfileName,
        userTotalFollowers,
        userTotalPosts,
        userProfileAddress,
        userProfileJob,
        followProfileBtn,
        contactProfileBtn,
        userPostsBtn;
public userItem user;
public RecyclerView postsList;
public LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
int currentPage = 1;
private HomeListAdapter mHomeListAdapter;
private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
public ImageView userProfilePicture, userProfileCover;
public LinearLayout actionProfileArea;
public int userID = 0;
private CacheManager mCacheManager;
private ThinDownloadManager downloadManager;

private Gson mGson;
LoadingView loginLoadingView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (M.getToken(this) == null) {
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);

        startActivity(mIntent);
        finish();

    } else {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_preview);
        initializeView();
        loginLoadingView = (LoadingView)findViewById(R.id.loginLoadingView);
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("userID")) {
            userID = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("userID");
        }
        mCacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

        mGson = new Gson();
        getUser();
        getPosts();
    }

}

private void initializeView() {
    downloadManager = new ThinDownloadManager(AppConst.DOWNLOAD_THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
    userProfileName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileName);
    userProfilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);
    userTotalFollowers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userTotalFollowers);
    userTotalPosts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userTotalPosts);
    followProfileBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.followProfileBtn);
    contactProfileBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contactProfileBtn);
    actionProfileArea = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.actionProfileArea);
    userProfileAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileAddress);
    userProfileJob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileJob);
    userProfileCover = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileCover);
    userPostsBtn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.userPostsBtn);
    userPostsBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    followProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    contactProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    postsList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.postsList);

    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeHome);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

    postsList.setOnScrollListener(new HidingScrollListener(layoutManager) {
        @Override
        public void onHide() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onShow() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoadMore(int currentPage) {
            setCurrentPage(currentPage);
            getPosts();
        }
    });
}



private void getUser() {
    if (M.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
        loginLoadingView.setLoading(true);
        UsersAPI mUsersAPI = APIService.createService(UsersAPI.class, M.getToken(this));
        mUsersAPI.getUser(userID, new Callback<userItem>() {
            @Override
            public void success(userItem user, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                try {
                    mCacheManager.write(mGson.toJson(user), "Profile-" + userID + ".json");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateView(user);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                loginLoadingView.setLoading(false);
                M.T(ProfilePreview.this, getString(R.string.ServerError));
            }
        });

    } else {

        try {
            String profile = mCacheManager.readString("Profile-" + userID + ".json");
            Gson mGson = new Gson();
            updateView((userItem) mGson.fromJson(profile, new TypeToken<userItem>() {
            }.getType()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            M.L(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

private void downloadFile(String url, String hash) {
    if (getFilePath(hash) == null) {
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(M.getFilePath(getApplicationContext(), hash));
        DownloadRequest downloadRequest = new DownloadRequest(downloadUri)
                .setDestinationURI(destinationUri);
        downloadManager.add(downloadRequest);
    }
}

private void updateView(userItem user) {
    this.user = user;
    if (user.isMine()) {
        actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        actionProfileArea.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    if (user.isFollowed()) {
        followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
        contactProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.Follow));
        contactProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    if (user.getName() != null) {
        userProfileName.setText(user.getName());
    } else {
        userProfileName.setText(user.getUsername());
    }
    if (user.getAddress() != null) {
        userProfileAddress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userProfileAddress.setText(user.getAddress());
    } else {
        userProfileAddress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (user.getJob() != null) {
        userProfileJob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        userProfileJob.setText(user.getJob());
    } else {
        userProfileJob.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    if (getFilePath(user.getPicture()) != null) {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(new File(getFilePath(user.getPicture())))
                .transform(new CropSquareTransformation())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_holder)
                .error(R.drawable.image_holder)
                .into(userProfilePicture);
    } else {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(AppConst.IMAGE_PROFILE_URL + user.getPicture())
                .transform(new CropSquareTransformation())
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_holder)
                .error(R.drawable.image_holder)
                .into(userProfilePicture);
        downloadFile(AppConst.IMAGE_PROFILE_URL + user.getPicture(), user.getPicture());
    }
    if (user.getCover() != null) {
        if (getFilePath(user.getCover()) != null) {
            userProfileCover.setImageURI(Uri.parse(getFilePath(user.getCover())));
        } else {
            Picasso.with(this)
                    .load(AppConst.IMAGE_COVER_URL + user.getCover())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.header)
                    .error(R.drawable.header)
                    .into(userProfileCover);
            downloadFile(AppConst.IMAGE_COVER_URL + user.getCover(), user.getCover());
        }
    } else {
        Picasso.with(this)
                .load(R.drawable.header)
                .into(userProfileCover);
    }
    userTotalFollowers.setText(user.getTotalFollowers() + "");
    userTotalPosts.setText(user.getTotalPosts() + "");
    loginLoadingView.setLoading(false);
}

private String getFilePath(String hash) {
    return M.filePath(getApplicationContext(), hash);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.followProfileBtn:
            UsersAPI mUsersAPI = APIService.createService(UsersAPI.class, M.getToken(this));
            mUsersAPI.followToggle(userID, new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
                @Override
                public void success(ResponseModel responseModel, Response response) {
                    if (responseModel.isDone()) {
                        if (user.isFollowed()) {
                            user.setFollowed(false);
                            followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.Follow));
                            loginLoadingView.setLoading(true);
                            contactProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            loginLoadingView.setLoading(false);
                        } else {
                            user.setFollowed(true);
                            followProfileBtn.setText(getString(R.string.UnFollow));
                            contactProfileBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    } else {
                        M.T(ProfilePreview.this, responseModel.getMessage());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    M.T(ProfilePreview.this, getString(R.string.ServerError));
                }
            });
            break;
        case R.id.contactProfileBtn:
            Intent messagingIntent = new Intent(this, MessagingActivity.class);
            messagingIntent.putExtra("conversationID", 0);
            messagingIntent.putExtra("recipientID", userID);
            startActivity(messagingIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.userPostsBtn:
            Intent userPostsIntent = new Intent(this, UserPosts.class);
            userPostsIntent.putExtra("userID", userID);
            startActivity(userPostsIntent);
            finish();
            break;
    }
}
public void getPosts() {
    if (M.isNetworkAvailable(this)) {

        if (!mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        }
        PostsAPI mPostsAPI = APIService.createService(PostsAPI.class, M.getToken(this));
        mPostsAPI.getUserPosts(userID, getCurrentPage(), new Callback<List<PostsItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void success(List<PostsItem> postsItems, retrofit.client.Response response) {
                try {
                    mCacheManager.write(mGson.toJson(postsItems), "UserPosts-" + userID + ".json");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                updateView(postsItems);
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                loginLoadingView.setLoading(false);
            }
        });
    } else {
        try {
            String UserPostsString = mCacheManager.readString("UserPosts-" + userID + ".json");
            updateView((List<PostsItem>) mGson.fromJson(UserPostsString, new TypeToken<List<PostsItem>>() {
            }.getType()));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void updateView(List<PostsItem> postsItems) {

    if (getCurrentPage() != 1) {
        List<PostsItem> oldItems = mHomeListAdapter.getPosts();
        oldItems.addAll(postsItems);
        mHomeListAdapter.setPosts(oldItems);
    } else {
        mHomeListAdapter.setPosts(postsItems);
    }
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()) {
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    setCurrentPage(1);
    getPosts();
}

public int getCurrentPage() {
    return currentPage;
}

public void setCurrentPage(int currentPage) {
    this.currentPage = currentPage;
}
```

}

Comment: [What is a `NullPointerException`, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) - The problem is `mHomeListAdapter` is `null`, likely because you **edit:** never initialise it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least from the code you posted you are not initialising your mhomelistadapter so it is null when you call setPosts